# Making a simple checkerboard

Tags: c, for-loop

I need help/hints printing a checkerboard in C.

I want to print a 4x4 checkerboard like this:

```
+----+
|    |
|    |
|    |
+----+
```

Naturally thats only 1x1 but I don't know how to do a 4x4 one.

I know I have to use some sort of nested for loop to do this. I also have to store it in an array. All I have is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char board[4][4];

int main() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            board[i][j] = 
        }
    }
```

I don't know how I would go about storing a 1x1 box in board[1][1] and then again in board[2][2]...you get the idea... Can you guys please help me how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you just want to print out the grid, or store it with values?

Comment: @Rob I want to print the grid but also store it in the array. 

This is only a part of a program I'm working on so if I were to impletement a console input and put 2,2 it should go to board[2][2] you know what I mean?

Comment: your array is [4][4] but you'll be referencing `i` and `j` values from 0..4 which will push you past the array bounds, so you'll be writing into memory you don't own.

Comment: @fbrereto: Okay, I edited the code by editing the for loop. But I still need to figure out how to store that pattern in the array...

Comment: Is your *question* primarily about how to store a board state in an array, or how to print a board in ASCII art?  Even if you need to do both, focus on one task at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that for every row, you will print `+` and then a `----+` for each column (or `|` and spaces):

```
+----+----+----+ ... ----+
|    |    |    | ...     |
.
.
.
|    |    |    | ...     |
+----+----+----+ ... ----+
|    |    |    | ...     |
```

And so on.

Also consider whether you need to store the *board state* or the *board drawing* in your arrays. The board state would be easier to analyze (and use less memory). When you need to "pretty print" the board, you can generate the drawing *from* the the board state array.

Comment: Oh and I want to store the board state. This is because if the user enters 2,3 I want it to go to board[2][3] and then maybe change that specific box.

Answer (score 1):

A board goes like this:

```
+---+---+
|   |   |
+---+---+
|   |   |
```

etc.

I would first print several separator elements:

```
while(i < n){
   printf("+---");
   i++;
}
printf("+\n");
```

Than several cells:

```
while(i < n){
printf("| %c ", currcell);
   i++;
} 
printf("|\n")
```

where `char curcell` would be your `board[i],[j]` - a whitespace by default.

Sorry if it doesn't look clear enough, i'm very new to programming.